# How to change fd-busy-indicator size

Tags: css, angular, sap-fiori

I'm using the fiori ngx library on angular. I am using the `<fd-busy-indicator>` for loading scrreens from [wiki](https://sap.github.io/fundamental-ngx/#/core/busyIndicator). But the sizes `s` is too small and `m` is too big for me. I tried to manually fix it by doing

```
::ng-deep fd-busy-indicator {
  width: 12px;      
  height: 12px;
}
```

but it did not work and the indicator became vertically alighed. Please tell me how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the style of individual circles. If you are using `m` sized then your css would look something like:

```
::ng-deep .fd-busy-indicator--m .fd-busy-indicator--circle-0,
::ng-deep .fd-busy-indicator--m .fd-busy-indicator--circle-1,
::ng-deep .fd-busy-indicator--m .fd-busy-indicator--circle-2 {
   width: 11px;
   height: 11px;
}
```